# How to access NSMutableArray index Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am getting NSMuttableArray cannot access in foreach statement. Anyone can guide how to get it in xamarin.ios c#?

I am having enum class as FontType, I need to change symbol to FontType

```
static NSMutableArray symbols;
foreach (var number in symbols)
{
    FontType d = symbols.IntValue
}
```

Comment: Can you use for loop with index instead of foreach?

Comment: I need to change that item to FontType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var number in NSArray.FromArray<T>(symbols))
{
}
```

or

```
foreach (var number in NSArray.FromArray<NSObject>(symbols))
{
}
```

Comment: how to convert that NSObject to FontTye

Comment: what's the FontType?UIFont?

Comment: I named Enum Class  as FontType

Comment: NSMutableArray array = new NSMutableArray(); 
   array.Add(NSNumber.FromInt32((int)FontType.First)); 
   var value = (FontType)array.GetItem<NSNumber>(0).Int32Value;